# How to get the default column width of an Excel sheet with Apache-POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

## Requirement

I need to get the **default column width** from a `XSSFSheet`.

## Approach

`XSSFSheet` has a method called `getDefaultColumnWidth()`:

```
public int getDefaultColumnWidth() {
    CTSheetFormatPr pr = worksheet.getSheetFormatPr();
    return pr == null ? 8 : (int)pr.getBaseColWidth();
}
```

## Problem

The method returns every time the same value, even if I change the default column width within Excel.

Obviously this method should return the default column width but I think it actually doesn't return the correct value.

### Cause

I checked with Excel itself what exactly happens:

1. I changed the default column width within Excel and saved the sheet.
2. I then look up the changes Excel made in the corresponding xml file:

   - The attribute `defaultColWidth` got changed.
   - The attribute `baseColWidth` stayed the same.

So the 'real' and correct default column width is stored within the `defaultColWidth` attribute. Therefore the method should return that attribute but instead it returns the **base column width** (as you can see in the implementation above).

### Solution

In my humble opinion, the method from above should return `pr.getDefaultColWidth()` and not `pr.getBaseColWidth()`.

I think either the method is wrongly implemented or I'm just too stupid to find the correct method which returns the correct value.

## Question

How can I get the *correct* **default column width** from an Excel `XSSFSheet` with POI Apache?

Regards winklerrr

Comment: Well, it says that it returns the basecolwidth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem remains unsolved even in `apache poi-5.0.0`.

If you try to get the `defaultColWidth`, it returns the `baseColWidth` which isn't expected.

So the workaround to get the `defaultColWidth` could be accessing the `CTWorksheet` to get the value.

```java
private double getDefaultColumnWidth(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    if (sheet.getCTWorksheet().isSetSheetFormatPr()) {
        CTSheetFormatPr pr = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetFormatPr();
        if (pr.isSetDefaultColWidth())
            // returns the actual default column width if it has been set
            return pr.getDefaultColWidth();
    }
    // tries to return the baseColWidth and in its absence returns 8
    return sheet.getDefaultColumnWidth();
}
```

There is a clear difference in the way `MSExcel` sets the defaultColWidth and
the way `apache poi-5.0.0` handles it.

`MSExcel` sets the default column width as `defaultColWidth`.

```xml
<sheetFormatPr defaultColWidth="2.5" defaultRowHeight="18.75"/>
```

This `XML` fragment was taken from the document generated by `apache poi-5.0.0`.`apache poi-5.0.0` sets the default column width as `baseColWidth`.

```xml
<sheetFormatPr baseColWidth="2.5" defaultRowHeight="18.75" customHeight="true"/>
```

I know it has been almost six years since this question had been last posted but it may be helpful to someone else I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
getDefaultColumnWidth

public int getDefaultColumnWidth()

Get the default column width for the sheet (if the columns do not define their own width) in characters.

Note, this value is different from getColumnWidth(int). The latter is always greater and includes 4 pixels of margin padding (two on each side), plus 1 pixel padding for the gridlines.

Specified by:
    getDefaultColumnWidth in interface Sheet
Returns:
    column width, default value is 8
```

The above clearly says that default shall be 8 if columns do not define their own. May be you are using the wrong API.

Comment: I think, you misunderstood my question. What you wrote is correct but it doesn't address my actual problem.
It's correct that the default value of the default column width is 8 but my problem is, that I changed that default value and the method still returns the same value.